# Is it possible to add multiple hyper-links to different positions of a image-view?

Tags: android, android-layout, hyperlink, imageview

I am having an [Customized imageview](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/) with pinchzoom and fling.I integrated with my app and it worked.But I need to add hyper links to the part of the image.I am having the x y position where I should set this hyper links.Is it possible to add multiple hyper-links to different position of an image-view.Actually its a magazine app so I need to show a page using a image-view.the page contain many hyper-links.The links in the image should be clickable so is it possible to add dynamically to the positions of a image-view?

Answer (score 1):

You can overlay that image with clickable transparent imageviews. That way you can have hyperlinks anywhere you like. You can make an image view transparent through setting its color to this #80000000  .

Comment: ya its possible but its a gud way to solve it since imageview has touch property transparent images will interupt the touch given to the parent imageview and also when it get zoomed the transparent images will not get zoomed.I tried ones its a tricky way to solve it if the parent image view has no touch and zoom functionality.